# converting row column result to row in sql

Tags: sql

I have Query like this

```
select convert(date,dtime) as Date, vtid,count(vtid) as count 
from Transaction_tbl 
group by cast(dtime as date),vtid 
order by  cast(dtime as date)
```

I am getting output lik this

### Out put

```
Date       vtid        count
---------- ----------- -----------
2013-05-07 7           4
2013-05-08 7           5
2013-05-08 8           3
2013-05-08 9           1
2013-05-09 7           3
2013-05-12 8           1
2013-05-13 8           1
2013-05-15 7           1
2013-05-15 9           1
```

but i need to get out put for particular date in same row,,

Expected Output

```
Date       vtid        count   vtid1   count1  vtid2  count2
-------------------------------------------------------------
2013-05-07   7           4      null    null    null   null    
2013-05-08   7           5       8        3        9    1
2013-05-09   7           3       null    null    null   null  
2013-05-12   8           1       null    null    null   null
```

if any one know how to do please help me....

Comment: Are there a variable number of values for vtid or is it always 7, 8, or 9?

Comment: vtid is the variable number

Comment: actually vtid is the some location id..example if i add one more loaction then new vtid will create as 10

Comment: if you have fixed/small cardinality of vtid column then you can do it using a single sql query. Otherwise you need to use procedure

Comment: how i can do with single sql query ,,can you show once

Comment: I have small cardinality of vtid ...thatsy

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not as dynamic as you were hoping, but it will produce something similar to your expected output for vtid 7, 8, and 9.

```
select d.Date, v7.vtid, v7.Count, v8.vtid, v8.Count, v9.vtid, v9.Count
from (select distinct convert(date,dtime) as Date from Transaction_tbl) as d
  left outer join (select convert(date,dtime) as Date, vtid, count(vtid) as Count from Transaction_tbl where vtid = 7 group by convert(date,dtime), vtid) as v7 on v7.Date = d.Date
  left outer join (select convert(date,dtime) as Date, vtid, count(vtid) as Count from Transaction_tbl where vtid = 8 group by convert(date,dtime), vtid) as v8 on v8.Date = d.Date
  left outer join (select convert(date,dtime) as Date, vtid, count(vtid) as Count from Transaction_tbl where vtid = 9 group by convert(date,dtime), vtid) as v9 on v9.Date = d.Date
order by d.Date
```

Full disclosure: I did not attempt to run this, there may be a typo in there

**Edit:** Though this might not produce output in a format that works for you, a pivot query is a bit cleaner and easier to modify

```
select *
from (
  select vtid, convert(date, create_date) as Date
  from Transaction_tbl
  where locid = 5
) as vt
pivot (
  count(vtid)
  for vtid in ([7], [8], [9])
) as pvt
```

Comment: Realized I forgot the "on" clauses

Comment: I didnt Get you,,,i run this query in sql server,,but i am getting same error

Comment: Column 'Transaction_tbl.vtid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you want to save that query as a procedure, you can just prepend "create proc MyProcName as" to the query, if my memory is correct. Then you could run it with "exec MyProcName". Of course, MyProcName could be whatever you want.

Comment: In above query i have to give one more filtering " i want to add where locid=5" ,,,so where i can add this?

Comment: left outer join (select convert(date,dtime) as Date, vtid, count(vtid) as Count from Transaction_tbl where vtid = 7 and Locid=5 group by convert(date,dtime), vtid) as v7 on v7.Date = d.Date

Comment: while executing your last query am getting out put like this

Comment: Date       7           8           9           10          11
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2013-05-07 4           0           0           0           0
2013-05-08 5           3           1           0           0
2013-05-09 3           0           0           0           0
2013-05-12 0           1           0           0           0 now column name is showing 7,8,9, insted of 7,8,9 how i can give normal,vip,vvip

Comment: i mean how i can change the column name,,,now i am getting column name 7,8,9,,,,,i want change the column name as normal,vip,vvip,

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your last posts until now. Hope you've figured out the rest. If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a PIVOT query with dynamic columns. There are several answers here on SO showing examples of this. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985946/685760), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797796/685760) or just [google it](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql+server+pivot+dynamic+columns). The difference you'll get from your desired result set is something like the following (numbers might be slightly out as I only took a cursory glance at your table above, but you'll get the idea);

```
Date       vtid-7     vtid-8      vtid-9   
2013-05-07   4           null      null
2013-05-08   5           3         1
2013-05-09   3           null      null
2013-05-12   null        1         null
2013-05-13   null        1         null
2013-05-15   1           null      1
```