# Return Table from SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables in an SQL Server 2008 database.  The first table contains users names, the second contains privileges and the last links the first two tables:

**USERS** (`ID` integer, `NAME` varchar(20));

**PRIVS** (`ID` integer, `NAME` varchar(50));

**USERS_PRIVS** (`USERID` integer, `PRIVID` integer);

For example, the USERS table has the following:

```
1, Adam
2, Benjamin
3, Chris
```

The PRIVS table has:

```
1, Add Invoice
2, Edit Invoice
3, Delete Invoice
```

The USERS_PRIVS table has:

```
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
3, 1
```

I am looking for a way to create an SQL query that would return something like the following:

```
          Add Invoice    Edit Invoice   Delete Invoice
Adam      Y              Y              Y
Benjamin  Y              Y              N
Chris     Y              N              N
```

Is this possible using the pivot function?

Comment: Yes.  There are many examples of `PIVOT` on this site and around the web; what have you tried?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: I tried a number of different pivot suggestions.  The problem I am having is getting the column headings from the PRIVS table instead of hardcoding them in the SQL as all of the suggestions below do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, [Add Invoice],[Edit Invoice],[Delete Invoice] FROM
(SELECT U.Name AS Name, P.Name AS PrivName FROM USERS_PRIVS UP
    INNER JOIN Users U ON UP.UserID = U.id
    INNER JOIN Privs P ON UP.PrivID = P.id) SB
PIVOT(
 count(SB.PrivName)
 FOR SB.PrivName in ([Add Invoice],[edit Invoice],[Delete Invoice])) AS Results
```

**EDIT 1:**
You will have to use some dynamic sql then.

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @privColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @privColumnNames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                                    FROM PRIVS FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query =
'SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT U.Name AS Name, P.Name AS PrivName FROM USERS_PRIVS UP
    INNER JOIN Users U ON UP.UserID = U.id
    INNER JOIN Privs P ON UP.PrivID = P.id) SB
PIVOT(
 count(SB.PrivName)
 FOR SB.PrivName in ( ' + @privColumnNames + ' )) AS Results ';

 execute(@query);
```

I borrowed the XML stuff from here [Dynamic Pivot Columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797691/dynamic-pivot-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: This works but I was hoping to avoid hard coding each privilege name as a column heading.  Is there a way to dynamically set the column names based on the privileges in the table?

Comment: @Caynadian see Edit 1. It uses dynamic sql to get a list of columns from your Privs Table

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/650f1/22/0).

```
with cl 
as (
select u.NAME , case when p.ID = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Add Invoice',
case when p.ID = 2 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Edit Invoice',
case when p.ID = 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Delete Invoice'
from USERS u inner join USERS_PRIVS up on u.ID = up.USERID
inner join PRIVS p on up.PRIVID = p.ID  
)

select NAME, MAX([Add Invoice]) 'Add Invoice', 
MAX([Edit Invoice]) 'Edit Invoice',
MAX([Delete Invoice]) 'elete Invoice'
from cl
group by NAME
```

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/650f1/25/0).

```
select NAME , case when [Add Invoice] = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Add Invoice',
case when [Edit Invoice] = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Edit Invoice',
case when [Delete Invoice] = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end 'Delete Invoice'
from (
select u.NAME, p.NAME as pname
from USERS u inner join USERS_PRIVS up on u.ID = up.USERID
inner join PRIVS p on up.PRIVID = p.ID  
) p
pivot( count(pname) for pname in ([Add Invoice], [Edit Invoice], [Delete Invoice])) as pvt
```

Comment: Your second script works but I was hoping to avoid hard coding each privilege name as a column heading.  Is there a way to dynamically set the column names based on the privileges in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    name,
    CASE [1] WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as 'Add Invoice', 
    CASE [2] WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as 'Edit Invoice', 
    CASE [3] WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as 'Delete Invoice'
from 
    (select name, userId, privid, 1 temp from users_privs join users on id = userid) as sourceTable
    pivot( min(temp) for privid in ([1], [2], [3])) as pivotTable
```

Comment: This works but I was hoping to avoid hard coding each privilege name as a column heading.  Is there a way to dynamically set the column names based on the privileges in the table?