# How to display results from SQL JOIN as separate columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, pivot

I am trying to join two tables and then parse out the results into separate columns like so:

Table1:

```
Customer_ID
----------
1
2
3
```

Table2:

```
Customer_ID ListID
------------------
1           1
1           2
1           5
2           1
2           3
```

Desired Results:

```
Customer_ID ListID1 ListID2 ListID3
-----------------------------------
1           1       2       5
2           1       3   
3
```

I used a LEFT JOIN to combine the tables and a GROUP BY to group columns with the same Custmer_ID as shown here:

```
SELECT MIN([Table1].[Customer_ID])
    ,MIN([Table2].[ListID])
FROM [Table1]
LEFT JOIN [Table2]
ON [Table2].[Customer_ID] = [Table1].[Customer_ID]
GROUP BY [Table1].[Customer_ID]
```

Current Results:

```
Customer_ID ListID
------------------
1           1
2           1
3           NULL
```

I can't figure out where to go from here to parse the ListID's into separate columns.  Is there a way to iterate through the ListID's?

Comment: Please look into pivot function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797691/dynamic-pivot-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unique in that the column that you want to pivot for doesn't exist.  You can create it with the `Row_number` window function.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, [1] ListID1, [2] ListID2, [3] ListID3
FROM
(select Table1.Customer_ID, 
    Table2.ListID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by Table1.Customer_ID Order By Table2.ListID) RowNum
from Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table2.[Customer_ID] = Table1.[Customer_ID]) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
max(ListID)
FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable
```

This will only show the top three `ListID` values in the columns.  You can add more `RowNum` values if you need more.

Comment: This worked, thank you soo much!!  I will definitely go and research more on pivot tables.